# SSH Key ask to enter passphrase after start-agent

Tags: git, bash, ssh, ssh-keys

I have 2 ssh key for 2 different accounts on Bitbucket.

The below is my bachrc file:

```
# Note: ~/.ssh/environment should not be used, as it
#       already has a different purpose in SSH.

env=$HOME/.ssh/agent.env

# Note: Don't bother checking SSH_AGENT_PID. It's not used
#       by SSH itself, and it might even be incorrect
#       (for example, when using agent-forwarding over SSH).

agent_is_running() {
    if [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
        # ssh-add returns:
        #   0 = agent running, has keys
        #   1 = agent running, no keys
        #   2 = agent not running
        ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2 -l >/dev/null 2>&1 || [ $? -eq 1 ]
    else
        false
    fi
}

agent_has_keys() {
    ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>&1
}

agent_load_env() {
    . "$env" >/dev/null
}

agent_start() {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >"$env")
    . "$env" >/dev/null
}

if ! agent_is_running; then
    agent_load_env
fi

# if your keys are not stored in ~/.ssh/id_rsa or ~/.ssh/id_dsa, you'll need
# to paste the proper path after ssh-add
if ! agent_is_running; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
elif ! agent_has_keys; then
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
fi

unset env

agent_stop() {
    if [ ${SSH_AGENT_PID+1} == 1 ]; then
        ssh-add -D
        ssh-agent -k > /dev/null 2>&1
        unset SSH_AGENT_PID
        unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    fi
}

agent_stop
```

**Why do I call agent_stop?**

That's for testing. I figured out that when agent_stop is called, all ssh keys are removed from agent and then when opened git bash again, the agent automatically adds ssh keys.

But only id_rsa doesn't prompt passphrase, the id_rsa_2 prompt everytime.

P/S: The public key of id_rsa_2 is added on Bitbucket.

What am I missing for this?

Comment: passphrase is prompted because you input a passphrase when generating key-pairs, IMHO.

Comment: Hi @gzh: We all do that when generate ssh by ssh-keygen. How can we overcome this?

Comment: When you run ssh-keygen, there is one step ask you whether you need a passphrase, you can click enter to skip or enter a passphrase, if my memory serve me correctly.

Comment: @gzh: thank you so much, you're right. It has option to skip passphrase

Answer (score 1):

Note: if you generate an ssh key without passphrase

```
cd
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ".ssh/mykey" -C "key for xxx acess" -q -P ""
```

Then you don't need ssh-agent at all

Comment: I will take a look on that. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

> When you run ssh-keygen, there is one step ask you whether you need a
>   passphrase, you can click enter to skip or enter a passphrase, if my
>   memory serve me correctly

From gzh